# Moving Zend Framework 2 from apache to nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, configuration, virtualhost, zend-framework

I would like to move site that uses Zend Framework 2 from Apache to Nginx. The problem is that site have 6 modules, and apache handles it by aliases defined in httpd-vhosts.conf,

```
#httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName localhost:443

Alias /develop/cpanel "C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_cp/public"
Alias /develop/docs/tech "C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_tech_docs/public"
Alias /develop/docs "C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_docs/public"
Alias /develop/auth "C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public"
Alias /develop "C:/webapps/develop/mil_web_dicom_viewer/public" 

DocumentRoot "C:/webapps/mil_catele_homepage"
</VirtualHost>
```

in httpd.conf DocumentRoot is set to C:/webapps. Sites are avialeble at for example `localhost/develop/cpanel`. Framework handles further routing.

In Nginx I was able to make only one site available by specifing `root   C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_tech_docs/public;` in server block. It works only because docs module don't depend on auth like others, and site was at `localhost/`.

In next attempt:

```
root   C:/webapps;
location  /develop/auth {
    root   C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /develop/mil_catele_auth/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Now as I enter `localhost/develop/cpanel` it gets to correct index.php but can't find any resources (css,js files). I have no Idea why reference paths in browswer's GET requsts changed to `https://localhost/css/bootstrap.css` form `https://localhost/develop/auth/css/bootstrap.css` as it was on apache. This root directive seems not working.

Nginx handles php by using fastCGI

```
location ~ \.(php|phtml)?$ {        
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param   APPLICATION_ENV  production;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I googled whole day, and found nothing usefull. Can someone help me make this configuration work like on Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `root` directive inside `location` blocks.

Try this:

```
location /develop/auth {
    alias C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

With this configuration, URLs work like this:

`http://example.com/develop/auth/image.png` -> `C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public/image.png`

If you use `root` instead of `alias`, you would get:

`C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public/develop/auth/image.png` instead.

And then, for some non-existing file / directory:

`http://example.com/develop/auth/not-existing` ->
`C:/webapps/develop/mil_catele_auth/public/index.php` would be run.

Hope this works the way you want it to work.